# convert iplImage to sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr

Tags: ros, cvbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have some problem to understand how to convert images with cvbridge. I red the tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages .

But I can't find a way to convert a openCV images to ROS images message. I succed to convert from ROS to openCV.
I wanted to use the function toImageMsg() but it returns a sensor_msgs::Image but I want a sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr.
Can somebody help me please?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153716/convert-iplimage-to-sensor_msgs::imageconstptr/) by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the following:

```
sensor_msgs::Image my_image = <somehow get this image with toImageMsg()>;
sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr my_image_const_ptr = &my_image;
```

`sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr` is nothing else than a constant shared pointer to a `sensor_msgs::Image`.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-16**:
I did :
sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr img_const = &img;
I have this error:
conversion from ‘IplImage** {aka *IplImage**}’ to non-scalar type ‘sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image*std::allocator<void > >}’ requested 
I declared "img" like : 
IplImage *img

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-04-16**:
I updated my answer. my_image should be the result of toImageMsg() I guess

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-16**:
So first I have to conver my IplImage to a cv_bridge::CvImagePtr, because you can only use toImageMsg() on a cv_bridge::CvImagePtr.
Do you know how to do it?